# Show of Power used to emulate a merit such as Armor of Scars

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Say a demon meets a vampire that uses Armor of Scars (Night Horrors: Immortal Sinners p.101) at merit level 4 (4 dots in the merit).

If the demon uses Armor of Scars through Show of Power, would that mean that he can emulate at the 4 dot use or just as the 1 dot (1 success as per Show of Power)?

I would assume it would be at whatever he saw (at the 4 dot merit level).  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Show of Power emulates automatic effects precisely**

Page 114 of *Flowers of Hell*, emphasis mine:

> If it is an inherent ability or Merit, the demon benefits from it until the end of the scene. *Otherwise*, it lasts as long as it normally would and has the same effect as if the demon's player had scored a single success on any required roll.

So, here would be the sequence of events: the player running Demon Debbie declares his intention for Debbie to mimic the damage resistant Vampire Vinnie that Debbie saw the other week. The ST looks at his notes, sees that Vinnie had *Armor of Scars* at 4 dots for damage mitigation, so, when Debbie's player rolls at least one success, she benefits from the 4 dot version of *Armor of Scars*, what she witnessed.

Later, Debbie is trying to emulate something she saw Promethean Paula do: *Dopplelganger: Incriminate* (PtC:2nd, page 133), wherein Paula scapegoated someone for a week (Paula rolled an Extraordinary Success, 5+ successes)

Debbie's dice hit the table again, but because she's trying to emulate an ability whose success hinges upon a dice roll (how many days the scapegoating lasts), Debbie can frame her victim for either 1 day (1 - 4 successes on Debbie's roll) or 3 days (Exceptional Success, 5+ successes on Debbie's roll.)

Basically, if no dice were needed for the original effect to transpire, the Demon can perfectly emulate it. If a roll was needed, the Demon can emulate it weakly. *Armor of Scars* requires no dice roll to active; so the Demon gets whatever intensity they saw.

Comment: Thanks Geist for your answer.  What do you think about powers such as Mage Sight or Peer across the Gauntlet from first edition?  My ST is thinking unless a power is "visible" in some way (qualifying it to be "seen"), then the power isn't able to be copied.   Does this sound right?  In other words, unless someone LOOKS at you with Mage Sight, you can't emulate it.   Even if the mage looks at someone else since it's not "seen" by the Demon.

Comment: 1/2: I don't believe the published books offer a definitive answer about powers which the Demon can't perceive. To argue against their allowance, one could interpret the powers of supernaturals as being an extension of their will; without being able to "visualize" the effect, the Demon can't mimic it. Or, one could interpret supernatural powers as tapping into reality itself - which Demons can manipulate, even if they can't see. Imagine the character is deaf; seeing someone move their mouth saying something wouldn't give the ability for the character to mimic their voice;

Comment: 2/2: seeing them play the violin would allow the character to pick up the violin and attempt to play - and a Demon has eidetic memory and considerable muscle control, so they could make a remarkable approximation without being able to judge it for themselves. So, the interpretation of whether powers are intrinsic to the wielder or are tapping into reality in general is something best judged on a troupe by troupe basis, and should be a consensus between ST and players.